# Create custom page in Prestashop 1.5.3

Tags: prestashop

I'd like to create a custom page in Prestashop 1.5.3 without using CMS.

Unfortunately I can not find any tutorials that are working with 1.5.3.

So far I have created a test.php file in the shops root directory with following content:

```
<?php
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php');

$smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'test.tpl');
?>
```

I placed the corresponding test.tpl in my themes basefolder. It simply contains 'hello world'.

I changed the blockmenu.php and created a custom link to my page:

```
$this->_menu .= '<li><a href="test.php">TEST</a></li>'.PHP_EOL;
```

If I click the link the page is displayed but the html is some kind of corrupt. The body-id of the page is set to *pagenotfound* and the left column is generated but is not shown. Is there any way to set the $page_name for my custom page so that I can check if my custom page is loaded and to supress the generation of the left and right columns?

Is there any other way to create a functional custom page without CMS?

Comment: http://blog.gofenice.com/prestashop/creating-custom-front-page-in-prestashop/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just create a controller with the name you want for the page, and put it in /overrides/controllers/front/.
The name of the controller must be NameyouwantforthepageController.php

Here is a basic class that will work:

```
class MyPageController extends FrontController {

/**
 *  Initialize controller
 *  @see FrontController::init()
 */
public function init() {
    parent::init();
}

/**
 *  Assign template vars related to page content
 *  @see FrontController::initContent()
 */
public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();

    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'my-page.tpl');
}

}
```

Take a look at the FrontController to see what method you need to override to add functionnalities, for example `setMedia()` to add CSS / JS files.

You will then be able to add a pretty url in the back office in the SEO panel.

Comment: Don't forget to set the class attribute `public $php_self = 'mypage';` to be able to select the page related in SEO & URLs menu.

Comment: Hello and Thanks for the response, but how can i access to my webpage, which URL do i have to use ?

Comment: @FabienPapet You can access the page with `www.yoursite.com/index.php?controller=nameOfYourController`. But the best way is to add a url in the SEO panel in the back office

Comment: @romainberger, Hi sir, I believe this method is more accurate than creating direct php and tpl files at the root folder (as suggested by OP). One question please: Do the new created controllers will not be lost after update. Thanks?

Comment: @romainberger .Well, I think you should edit this answer from `/controllers/front/` to `/overrides/controllers/front/`. You agree with me??

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces yep, definitely. Edited my answer. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I tried this approach in PS 1.6, but I can't access the page via the link @romainberger provided. How can I do that in this version?

Comment: All I needed to do was to clear the cache by removing file 'cache/class_index.php' as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23764120/1101730

Answer (score 8):

All is working good except the "public $php_self = 'mypage'".

If you put your file in the override directory (good practice), the identifier "mypage" doesn't be shown on the SEO Menu.
But, if you put your controller file in the main directory, it is working.

The classes/Meta.php doesn't scan the override directory, only the root directory (you can see it on line 56 of Meta.php)

Overriding the class Meta.php with this code allow PrestaShop to scan the override directory and add the pages :

```
class Meta extends MetaCore
{


    public static function getPages($exclude_filled = false, $add_page = false)
    {
                $selected_pages = parent::getPages($exclude_filled, $add_page);


        if (!$files = Tools::scandir(_PS_CORE_DIR_.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'override'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'controllers'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'front'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 'php', '', true))
            die(Tools::displayError('Cannot scan override directory'));

        $exlude_pages = array(
            'category', 'changecurrency', 'cms', 'footer', 'header',
            'pagination', 'product', 'product-sort', 'statistics'
        );

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            if ($file != 'index.php' && !in_array(strtolower(str_replace('Controller.php', '', $file)), $exlude_pages))
            {
                $class_name = str_replace('.php', '', $file);
                $reflection = class_exists($class_name) ? new ReflectionClass(str_replace('.php', '', $file)) : false;
                $properties = $reflection ? $reflection->getDefaultProperties() : array();
                if (isset($properties['php_self']))
                    $selected_pages[$properties['php_self']] = $properties['php_self'];
                elseif (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_.-]*\.php$/i', $file))
                    $selected_pages[strtolower(str_replace('Controller.php', '', $file))] = strtolower(str_replace('Controller.php', '', $file));
                elseif (preg_match('/^([a-z0-9_.-]*\/)?[a-z0-9_.-]*\.php$/i', $file))
                    $selected_pages[strtolower(sprintf(Tools::displayError('%2$s (in %1$s)'), dirname($file), str_replace('Controller.php', '', basename($file))))] = strtolower(str_replace('Controller.php', '', basename($file)));
            }   
        }

        return $selected_pages;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a custom page controller in the override directory - override/controllers/front/CustompageController.php

```
class CustompageController extends FrontController{ 

    //add js / css required for the custom page

    public function setMedia(){
        $this->context->controller->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'custom-page.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS(_THEME_CSS_DIR_.'custom-page.css');
        parent::setMedia();
    }

    public function initContent(){

        //preparingdata for passing to the custom page
        $name = 'Gofenice Technologies';
        $expert_in = array('Prestashop Development', 'Prestashop Customization', 'Prestashop Custom Module Development', 'Prestashop Page Speed Optimization');
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'company_name' => $name,
                'expert_in' => $expert_in
            ));
        //data ends-here

        //pass data to template file
        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'custom-page.tpl');


        //show left/ right columns - will be true and shown by default
        $this->display_column_left = false;
        $this->display_column_right = false;

        //call parent initcontent - this is for loading the site's default header, footer, left and right columns
        parent::initContent();
    }
}
```

2. A template for our new custom page - themes/site-current-theme/custom-page.tpl

   ```
   <h3>{$company_name}</h3>
   <p><strong>{l s='Expert In'}</strong></p>
   <ul>
       {foreach from=$expert_in item=skill}
       <li>{$skill}</li>
       {/foreach}
   </ul>
   ```

[creating custom front page in prestashop](http://blog.gofenice.com/prestashop/creating-custom-front-page-in-prestashop/)

Comment: Why I still see a blank page instead of my view?

Comment: please enable error mode by editing /config/defines.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

Hello geys this solution work perfectlly with override also.

1/ in the folder /override create page manufacturer-detail.php and put this code:

include(dirname(**FILE**).'/config/config.inc.php');
  Controller::getController('ManufacturerDetailController')->run();

Tools::displayFileAsDeprecated();

include(dirname(**FILE**).'/header.php');

$smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'manufacturer-detail.tpl');

include(dirname(**FILE**).'/footer.php');

2/ In the folder /override/controllers/front create page manufacturerDetailController.php and put this code:

class ManufacturerDetailController extends FrontController{

```
/*public $php_self = 'manufacturer-detail';  */  /* optional */

public function init(){ 
    parent::init(); 
} 

public function initContent(){ 
    parent::initContent(); 
    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'manufacturer-detail.tpl'); 
} 

 /*  The following code portion is optional.
```

*  Remove the double-slashes to activate the portion
   *  if you want to use external stylesheet and JavaScript for the page.
   *  Create the CSS and JS files in the css and js directories of the theme accordingly
   */

```
//public function setMedia(){
  //parent::setMedia();
  //$this->addCSS(_THEME_CSS_DIR_.'custom-page.css');
  //$this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'custom-page.js');
//}
```

}

3/ in the folder /themes/your-default-theme create page manufacturer-detail.php and put this code:

## Hello world

4/ You can go to SEO & URLs in your back office and add new url

You can access tou your page http://yourstore.com/index?controller=ManufacturerDetail

OR

http://yourstore.com/urr-you-have-added-from-back-office

Comment: Why after setting custom url ind SEO & URL in 1.6 I am redirected back to "ugly" link? When I go to http://yourstore.com/rewrited-link it moves me back into http://yourstore.com/index?controller=NotRewritedControler

EDIT: I found it - weird but after creating 1 url I was able to select another controller and then it worked.