# prestashop 1.6 custom page don't work?

Tags: prestashop

I have create a Test controller  using the code in  : [Create Custom page in Prestashop 1.5.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336006/create-custom-page-in-prestashop-1-5-3)

```
class MyPageController  extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'mypage';

public function init() {
    parent::init();
}


public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();
    die('test!');
    }
}
```

I put it in the /controllers/front/MyPageController.php and it does not work. i get a clean html page.

What am I missing ?

link to custom page : http://www.funtoy.co.il/index.php?controller=MyPage

Edit 1 :
fix the semicolon at $php_self = 'mypage';

Thanks.
yaniv abo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove `cache/class_index.php` to clear the cache.

Comment: I have added a semicolon, still the same problem.