# Are new added controllers to Prestashop controllers folder deleted after update?

Tags: prestashop, controllers, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6, custom-pages

I feel the answer is no, but i am not sure yet because I am a newbie in Prestashop.

**Situation:**

I need to create a custom page in Prestashop without using CMS (due to its limitations). I found  here in SO that the one manner is :[Create custom page in Prestashop 1.5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336006/create-custom-page-in-prestashop-1-5-3)

I just want before implementing this to be sure that the future updates don't break the behaviour.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the Controller in the override, not the core. Then it will not get updated (like the core, which just gets replaced by the update)

Core controller are located in:

```
../Controllers/*
```

These will be overwritten when you update

Overrides / Extension Controllers can be put in

```
../override/controllers/*
```

and will not be touched by an update!

Comment: Thank you for your time, but my controller is new and is overriding nothing. I thought /overrides folder is only for overriding existing controllers. What about new controllers like indicated in the link i provided in question?

Comment: updated the answer, its also for extensions! you could also write your own module, but I feel this would be an overkill in your situation. The folder is required so that you can make your controller inherit, in your example, frontcontroller.

Comment: Now I understand. /overrides folder is also for extensions. And creating a module just for custom page is an exageration. am I right? +1 and wainting for 5 minutes so that I can accept. Thank you very much for your time and clarifications.

Comment: as of my understanding, yes! A module would be an overkill because you don't really add any functionality, as I understand you take it away. best regards

Comment: Np, mate any time! You too! Just to complete it, I'm not 100% positive that your controller would get overritten in the normal controllers folder in the event of an update, but for sake of consitency and a "pretty" programming style I would add it there. In any cms/eCommerce system there are usually folders for your code specifically, so you and every other developper can see the changes that are made, that differ from the core system.

Comment: I see what you mean. It belongs to good practices making modifications outside of core folders.  Your comprehensive answer is appreciated.