# How to create a Prestashop custom page and how to call that in url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prestashop

How to create a Prestashop custom page and how to call that in url.

```
<?php
    include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
    include(dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php');

    $smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'html-template.tpl');

    include(dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create custom page in Prestashop 1.5.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336006/create-custom-page-in-prestashop-1-5-3)

Comment: Yes  yenshirak, and that question also features the 'right' answer: just use a controller, no modules needed. New front controllers in modules should be used only for pages strictly related to the module's functionality.

Also, the solution works with v1.6.x too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new PS module
2. Create a file in your module folder: `controllers/front/action.php`
3. Define this class:

`YouModuleNameActionModuleFrontController extends FrontController {}`

4. Take example front other module and fill in you controller logic. Most importantly set your own template `$this->setTemaplate('templa.tpl')`, which located `yourmodulename/views/templates/front/templa.tpl`
5. Install your module, then output a link somewhere in PS (just to get hte link) `Context::getContext()->link->getModuleLink('yourmodulename', 'action')`
6. Visit this URL and see if you template works.
7. If you want friendly URL, go to SEO & URLs, click add and select yourmodulename-action